# Error No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener

Tags: java, android, textview, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I'm using CollapsingToolbarLayout in Activity class, when I built I saw an exception following as:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.totoroads.android.app, PID: 4596
              java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(Landroid/view/View;Landroid/support/v4/view/OnApplyWindowInsetsListener;)V in class Landroid/support/v4/view/ViewCompatLollipop; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.support.v4.view.ViewCompatLollipop' appears in /data/data/com.totoroads.android.app/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.2.0_aca63e91a3783d676855828331e4814bb550d297-classes.dex)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$LollipopViewCompatImpl.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:1558)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(ViewCompat.java:2829)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:429)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:316)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:281)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                  at com.totoroads.android.app.DetailListCarActivityDemo.onCreate(DetailListCarActivityDemo.java:33)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My dependencies:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.totoroads.android.app"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
 }

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
// compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.3'
//compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
// compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.3'
compile 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
// compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
//compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
// compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
// compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.etsy.android.grid:library:1.0.5'
// check version: http://www.technotalkative.com/lazy-productive-android-developer-part-6-staggered-gridview/
compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha8'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.0.0'
// compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.2.0'
  }
```

It's seem there are things wrong in library, How to fix exception, thank you so much !!

Comment: look at this line `com.totoroads.android.app.DetailListCarActivityDemo.onCreate(DetailListCarActivityDemo.java:33)`

Comment: Yes, I know, but its seem not detail for me

Comment: You're using different versions of all your support libraries. You've also got redundant entries in the dependencies. E.g., `design` already depends on `support-v4` and `appcompat-v7`, so you can just remove those.

Comment: Maybe I should update to same version

Comment: I have updated same version and it worked, thank you

Comment: No problem. Please select the "That solved my problem!" button so we know your question has been answered. Thanks. Cheers!